# Spring Security taglib cannot be found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I put `<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>`

I will recieve the following error:

```
The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

But I have *spring-security-taglibs-3.1.3* et al in my */lib* folder. Does anyone know what else am I missing?

Comment: Did you start the SpringSecurity listener on web.xml?

Answer (score 75):

Adding this dependency fixed it for me (using 3.1.X.RELEASE) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>${your-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The taglib now works properly:

`<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>`

Comment: Yeah but what version should I pick?

Answer (score 15):

**Make sure the following dependencies are included**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using jetty 9 (jetty-maven-plugin)
The above could not help. So added below code to WEB-INF/web.xml and it worked like charm:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.xsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.JSP</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.JSPF</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.JSPX</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.XSP</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Also add to jetty-context.xml of the problem still persists:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
    <Call name="setAttribute">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
        <Arg>^$|.*/spring-[^/]*\.jar$|</Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```